# Can a preposition select a past participle?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, past-participles

> “I took it **for granted**.” (John Steinbeck, East of Eden)

I know this is an idiom. But it’s very strange that the preposition selected a -en word. I can’t imagine any other cases for this kind of combination. Is this just an exception, or can we use any other examples?

Comment: How is *granted* an -en word? Can you define what an -en word is?

Comment: @jwpat7, Oh, it's just an adverb, only happening to end with the ed.

Comment: In similar contexts you often say *"I take it as [a] **given** [that something or other is true]"*.

Comment: @jwpat7 It's a notation, conventional in many linguistic/grammatic texts, for a past participle form. Similarly: *-s* (for 3p sgl), *-ed* (for simple past), *-ing* (for gerund-participle, or whatever a specific grammatical sect wants to call it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *take X for Y* means to "assume that X is Y"; it may be used with both adjectival and nominal Ys:

> I took him for an idiot.
>   Let us take him for sincere.

(This use of *take* is, by the way, relatively rare in conversation today; but its opposite, *mis-take*, is very common: *I mistook him for sincere*)

*I took it for granted* is an adjectival use of the past participle, equivalent to saying

> I took it for something **which has been granted**.

*Grant* here originally had the sense of *concede*, as when we say

> Granted, he is an idiot ... *meaning "I concede that he is an idiot."*

In the same way, FumbleFingers' *take it as given* means *take it as something which has been given*—in logical discourse, a prior assumption, a term or proposition which is "given" to the argument from outside, at the beginning rather than deduced in the course of the argument.

Here are a few more examples of the *take it for/as*, with both adjectives and adjectival participles:

> take it for certain that ...
>   take it for indisputable that ...
>   take it for proven that ...
>   take it as decided that ...
>   take it as probable that ...